# Using `test` to check the existence of a variable

Tags: bootloader, u-boot

I am having some trouble using the test command in u-boot in the u-boot that shipped with the beagle bone black. I do not believe this is a beagle bone black issue.

```
if test -n $uenvcmd;
    then
        echo Running uenvcmd ...;
        run uenvcmd;
    fi;
```

In the above case I see -

```
test - minimal test like /bin/sh

Usage:
test [args..]
```

The variable `$uenvcmd` contains a script. However, if the content of the variable is anything other than a script, things work fine. Am I missing something? Is there a way around this problem?

---

For Carl Norum's Comment:

```
U-Boot# test -n $uenvcmd

U-Boot# test -n $bootcmd
test - minimal test like /bin/sh

Usage:
test [args..]

U-Boot# test -n "$bootcmd"
test - minimal test like /bin/sh

Usage:
test [args..]
U-Boot#
```

@CarlNorum - Added the output. `test -n $uenvcmd` seems to work now. I have changed the content of the variable. It looks like the problem is content dependent. $bootcmd has a lot of script and it does not work.

Comment: You should probably be quoting `"$uenvcmd"`.  Can you show a working and not-working case?

Comment: @CarlNorum - Added the output. `test -n $uenvcmd` seems to work now. I have changed the content of the variable. It looks like the problem is content dependent. $bootcmd has a lot of script and it does not work.